Name of BBC 1990s screenplay set in near future; migrants trying to enter Europe
Dim memories of this from my childhood - asking now, obviously, because it's so topical.
Set in some kind of Fortress Europe in the near future, lots of African migrants trying to get in (maybe a massive drought across Africa, millions on the move?).
The one scene I remember clearly are the police officers getting a woman to help identify someone from mug shots; she has a tag on her leg that will go off at a certain time and if she is not back over the European border by then she will not be allowed back in. 
She finally sees a face she identifies; the police drive back to the border at top speed (in an Audi?) but the alarm goes off a few minutes before they get there; the woman breaks down in tears and the police just look a bit guilty and uncomfortable.
Possibly ends with a European and an older African man talking about the prospects for the future.
Anyone know what I'm talking about? 

Yes I also remember that one and its not the one below... but I also cannot remember the title. However niggling at the back of my mind is (& don't take this as verbatim) - it was a mini-series & it had ad breaks (so not BBC). I want to say it was called "The Tunnel" but it certainly wasn't the recent anglo/french remake of "The Bridge". I also recall that there was a major plot point about postcards that were supposed to be sent from people who escaped. Also a pivotal scene during an escape through a tunnel with a electric handrail and a machine gun. Hope that helps.

Cannot confirm fully (as I haven't seen it since it was first on), but can I suggest "The March" as a possibility:

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165382/

It was a one-off TV movie that was part of a season of shows about world issues called "One world".

Hm, could be I'm conflating two different TV movies - 'The March' certainly sounds like a contender for one part of it, so thanks for that! I wonder what the other one was?

It sounds like the other one was Black Easter - full synopsis with spoilers here: http://www.screenonline.org.uk/tv/id/1177206/synopsis.html
